# How do I use ninject within an AreaRegistration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, areas

I have an 'Account' area within my mvc3 project.

It has an AreaRegistration class to limit visibility to registered-only users like so:

```
public class AccountAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Account";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Account_default",
            "{account}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new {account = new MustBeRegisteredAccount(DEPENDENCIES)},
            new string[] {"Continuum.Web.Areas.Account.Controllers"}
        );
    }
}
```

so how do i set up ninject to be able to resolve DEPENDENCIES / create the MustBeRegisteredAccount object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first try and use Constructor Injection (i.e., see if MVC internally uses the registered `DependencyResolver` to create instances of `AreaRegistration` classes too (havent found anythign one way or the other on whether that should work but there's a pretty quick way to find out empirically :D).

Failing that, using a `DependencyResolver.GetService<MustBeRegisteredAccount>()` is the [Service Locator (antipattern)](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) workaround in MVC land. (The Ninject.MVC3 extension deliberately doesn't expose a global Kernel instance as that would just encourage gratuitous use).

See http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html

Comment: DependencyResolver is not used to create instances of AreaRegistration.